# PHP Tidy package alternative

Tags: php, tidy

I have a PHP Script that loads an rss feed, parses it through Tidy (to create the object) then gets scanned through like an array to get all the values. But I am moving servers, and the new server doesn't have Tidy installed. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: SimplePie, lastRSS, MagpieRSS,Zend_Feed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for "php parse rss" (less the double quotes) and you'll find lots of libraries in PHP to parse an RSS feed.  Take your pick.

Here are a few:

[RSS PHP](http://rssphp.net/)

[Magpie RSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: cheers, i did have a look, but I was wondering if there were any good ones that could be recommended, cheers

Comment: Possibly you should reword your question then; if there are considerations beyond simply parsing the RSS e. g. "the library must be able to parse atom feeds as well" then spell that out.  Otherwise, see which one has the most downloads and go with that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [htmLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php) -- small and fast and doesn't require a PHP extension